# White growth on the outside bottom of the pot

Tags: plant-health

I have a question about a peace lily we are currently growing inside. We aren’t really sure what we are doing for this to be caused but there’s a white/yellow growth on the bottom of the pot and also burnt/dying leaves. I’m not sure if this is due to over watering, poor irrigation or under watering or if it’s just a general disease or whatever.

Any help would be great :)

Lachlan

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EnNx.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/40ehx.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over watering.  That's is slime mold growing on the bottom.  And the leaf browning in an indication of a watering problem.   The top of the soil should be dry, but 1-2" down it should be moist but not wet before you water again.  Put your finger in the soil to check.  Do not use a moisture metre. You can leave a wooden skewer in the pot and every now and then take it out to check to see how much water is in the soil.

If slightly moist 1-2" down, but not wet, water until water comes out the bottom.  Afterwards dump out the water in the saucer below.  Don't let your pot sit in it.  Sitting in water it will grow slime mold.

Wipe off the mold and then use some hydrogen peroxide to kill any spores left behind.

Comment: Wow. It *is* slime mold. I've never seen that one before!